# How to import a .csv file with double quotes in column values to SQL table

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, delimiter

I am trying to import the data from a .csv file to SQL table using SSIS data flow task. One row in my .csv file is like

```
Col1,Col2,Col3

1200,"ABC","Value is \"greater\" than expected"
```

While creating the Flat file connection, I have given Comma as Delimiter and " as Qualifier. And created a derived column (`REPLACE(Col3,"\"","")`) as the second step to remove `\"` from column3.

But as soon as I start running the package I get an error in the Flat file source itself as "Column delimiter for col3 was not found".

Can someone please guide me in solving this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that the csv file has the `\ ` to escape the `"`?  Usually a csv has `""` within a string to represent the `"` character...  *(It sounds as though the csv file may not be conforming to accepted standards, and the SSIS packaged believes that the string is ending and so expects a subsequence new line or comma.)*

Comment: It's not a valid CSV if it has quotes escaped like `\"`

Answer (score 1):

You may need to escape the slash too, try this please and let us know:

```
(REPLACE(Col3,"\\\"",""))
```